# Question about the TCP idle timeout to Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tcp, keep-alive

I found that the TCP idle timeout to Google Load Balancer is 600 seconds and I would like to try and confirm this thing.

I used the following command to do the test and expect to get the result about 600 seconds after waiting for the connection closed.

```
time telnet {LB IP} 80
```

In fact, I got this result.

```
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

real    4m0.015s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.001s
```

It was about 4 minutes and was not 600 seconds.

Is there somethings wrong? Any suggestions on how to test the TCP idle timeout value?

Thank you!

Comment: It was the server that implemented that timeout, Nothing you can do about it from the client end. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

TCP session Timeout value is fixed at 10 min (600 sec) and its value is not configurable by modifying your backend service.

I would suggest you to configure web server software used by your backends so that its keep alive timeout is longer that 600 seconds to prevent connections being closed prematurely by the backend. This timeout does not apply to websocket.

I ran the same command and for me as well it's 4 min.

For more information,go through the link [1].

@instance-1:~$ time telnet [LB IP] 80

Trying LB IP...

Connected to LB IP.

Escape character is '^]'.

Connection closed by foreign host.

real    4m0.017s

user    0m0.002s

sys     0m0.000s

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#timeouts_and_retries